# Laravel - Encriptar password con bcrypt y como recuperarlo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Tengo esta función para guardar los datos del usuario (email y password) , encriptando el password, esta función funciona y me inserta en la BD con el password encriptado.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
        'c_password' => 'required|same:password',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);
    }

    $input = $request->all();
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $user = User::create($input);
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken;
    $success['name'] =  $user->name;

    return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this-> successStatus);
}
```

El problema lo tengo al hacer la función de login para comprobar que el email y password sean correctos, para ello hago esto, primero compruebo que exista el usuario y luego intento hacer la comparación del password, pero siempre me devuelve false.

```
public function loginweb(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email',$request->get('email'))
            ->first();

    if (Hash::check($user->password, $request->get('password'))) {
        return response()->json($user,201);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json('User or password invalid',400);
    }

}
```

Gracias,